# Managing M2 projects with GIT (workflow)

Tags: magento2, database, git, workflow

I'm developing Magento projects for different merchants and I don't know if I'm working right, also have some doubts, any advice is welcome. I'll share my workflow.

1. **Initialize the project**

I install a fresh magento project using composer on local and create the git repository. I just use the default gitignore. I install the magento instance with CLI, the template and some modules that are required for the project. **I use submodules for install the modules that are reutilized for other merchants**. I think it's a good practice, I prefer it than use composer.

2. **Deploying project on production server**

When my local project is stable I deploy it on production server following these steps:

- backup my ddbb from local
- git clone on server
- run composer install
- install magento from CLI (I know, I will restore the ddbb after that, but I don't know why I have to install magento first, if I don't do it, something is broken.
- restore ddbb

At this point I have 2 instances of Magento exactly equals, on local and on production server.

3. **Deploying categories, products, attributes, images, etc on production server**

I use some software that transfers all products stuff on magento via API. I have to do that on production server, **I need a public url**. When finished that, I need to backup the ddbb and restore it on local for mantain the 2 instances equals.
But now I have the first problem, I don't have the product images, because of gitignore. Don't know if it's good to keep working like that, without images, or just add all that stuff on git too.

4. **Customizing the website**

Now is when all troubles goes up. The project is stable but need to modify some things, (sometimes an entire functionality, you know that world :D) I try to keep working always in local, commit and push, but sometimes I need an interaction from merchant that will configure on production server, or just have to try things on production server, editing some configurations... And it's a headache have to think always what instance of magento is newer, backing up and restoring from one or another instance, etc.

**Conclusions**

Don't know if I'm doing the best practices, just wanted to share my workflow, and receive some advices to improve. **The doubt I wanted to clear is what to do with images, I don't understand why the default gitignore tracks some folders on /pub/media (I've noticed playing with wysiwyg, when you upload images it tracks on git) but the product images are ignored (not sure now where are saved) I think I'll be better having all images on local, but don't know if will enlarge so much the project.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sync all the images between local and production with Rsync (Tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps) . Normally only the theme images are added to git and the images in pub/media are ignored.